# Issues in dynamic crawling of vbulletin

Tags: python, html, screen-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy

disclaimer : Excuses for my stupidity but I am not a web programmer :D

I'm trying to write a crawler using python scrapy. I'm encountering some strange behaviour when I look at this [vbulletin](http://forums.heroesofnewerth.com/index.php) board. When I load the page in firefox and inspect it using firefox/firebug I see the forum L1 header have the class `forumbit_nopost new L1` (you can search for cat117 in the document to get to an element of interest).

When I retrieve the document using scrappy or curl I get the class set to `forumbit_nopost old L1`. I changed the user agent to match firefox's when using curl and it made no difference, so I suspect it has to do with some javascript executing. I have tried disabling javascript in firefox, but firefox still has source which has the `new` variant of the class attribute.

Could someone explain to me what is going on ? :D

P.s., chrome sees the `old` variant as well.

curl command used :

```
curl http://forums.heroesofnewerth.com/index.php --user-agent "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0" > scratch
```

Comment: I opened that page in Firefox 12 and Chrome 18 (Ubuntu 12.04) - i am getting `forumbit_post old` class everywhere. Maybe they were testing new layout/engine? Just a coincidence?

Comment: wget and chrome are serving "old" as at this date.

Comment: What are you trying to extract? Ignore the issue and xpath to something generic like "//h2@[class='forumtitle']/a"

Comment: I'm trying to extract the topology of the forum in it's entirety before I start traversing the posts.

Answer (score 0):

I would bet that new means there are new posts since your last visit. Your script would never show this unless it keeps cookies between sessions.